# Get a hierarchy of objects in Rails using one ActiveRecord call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple model called `Node` with a field called `parent_id`. The basic idea is that the root `Node` has `parent_id == nil` and then the other `Nodes` are using `parent_id` to reference their parent `Node`. Then I want to do a traversal of the Nodes (Depth First) like this:

```
def traverse(node) 
 node.children.each do |child_node|
  traverse(child_node)
 end
end
```

The only thing I want to avoid is doing multiple calls to the database to get my models. Can I get such a hierarchy in one query? If yes, then how?

I know I can do this with a query like `Node.all` and then make a code that builds the entire hierarchy, but I guess it's not the best practice. I would rather use something like the `Node.where(parent_id: nil).includes(children)` to only get the root along with the references, but I'm not sure about the sintax.